# Sum a value inside a loop in jinja

Tags: templates, variables, loops, jinja2

I have a for loop in a jinja template:

```
          <ul>
                {%- for t in tree recursive %}
                    <li><span class="li_wrap">
                        <span><i class="glyphicon {{ 'glyphicon-folder-close' if t.type == 'folder' else 'glyphicon-file'}}"></i> {{ t.name }}</span>
                        {% if t.type != 'folder' %}
                            <span class="pull-right">Size: {{ t.size/1000 }} kb </span> 
                        {% endif %}
                        </span>
                    {%- if t.children -%}
                        <ul>{{ loop(t.children) }}</ul>
                    {%- endif %}
                    </li>
                {%- endfor %}
          </ul>
```

what I want is to sum the value of `t.size` and use it as a total size number, but above this block.
What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must use the jinja function SUM =>  [http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#sum)

This code should work

```
 Total: {{ t|sum(attribute='size') }}
```